# Parser grammar rule is being ignored

Tags: parsing, antlr4, lexer

## The Goal

The goal is interpret plain text content and recognise patterns e.g. Arithmetic, Comments, Units of Measurements.

## Example Input

This would be entered by a user.

```
# This is an example comment
10 + 10
// Another comment
This is one line of text
Tested
```

## Expected Parse Tree

The goal of my grammar is to generate a tree that would look like this (if anyone has a better method I'd be interested to hear).

**Note:** The `10 + 10` is being recognised as an `arithmetic` rule.

[image: Goal output]

## Current Parse Tree aka The Problem

Below is the current output from the lexer and parser.

**Note:** The `10 + 10` is being recognised as an `text` and not the `arithmetic` rule.

[image: Current Output]

## Grammar Definition

The logic of the grammar at a high levels is as follows:

1. Parse line by line
2. Determine the line content if not fall back to text

```
grammar ContentParser;

/*
 * Tokens
 */
NUMBER: '-'? [0-9]+;
LPARAN: '(';
RPARAN: ')';
POW: '^';
MUL: '*';
DIV: '/';
ADD: '+';
SUB: '-';

LINE_COMMENT: '#' TEXT | '//' TEXT;
TEXT: ~[\n\r]+;
EOL: '\r'? '\n';

/*
 * Rules
 */
start: file;
file: line+ EOF;
line: content EOL;

content
    : comment 
    | arithmetic 
    | text
    ;

// Custom Content Types
comment: LINE_COMMENT;

/// Example taken from ANTLR Docs
arithmetic:
    NUMBER                                                          # Number
    | LPARAN inner = arithmetic RPARAN                              # Parentheses
    | left = arithmetic operator = POW right = arithmetic           # Power
    | left = arithmetic operator = (MUL | DIV) right = arithmetic   # MultiplicationOrDivision
    | left = arithmetic operator = (ADD | SUB) right = arithmetic   # AdditionOrSubtraction;

text: TEXT;
```

## My Understanding

The `content` rule should check for a match of the `comment` rule then followed by the `arithmetic` rule and finally falling back to the `text` rule which matches any character apart from newlines.

However, I believe that the lexer is being greedy on the `TEXT` tokens which is causing issues but I'm not sure.

(I'm still learning ANTLR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are writing a parser, it's always a good idea to print out the tokens for the input.

In the current grammar, `10 + 10` is recognized by the lexer as TEXT, which is not what is needed. The reason it is text is because that is the longest string matched by a rule. It does not matter in this case that the `TEXT` rule occurs after the `NUMBER` rule in the grammar. The rule is that Antlr lexers will always match the longest string possible of the given lexer rules. But, if it can match two or more lexer rules where the strings are of equal length, then the first rule "wins". The lexer works pretty much independently of the parser.

There is no way to reliably have spaces in a `text` string, and not have them in `arithmetic`. The fix is to push spaces and tabs into an "off-channel" stream, then reconstruct the text by looking at the start and end character indices of the first and last tokens for the `text` tree node. The tree is a little messier, but it does what you need.

Also, you should just name the grammar as "Context" not "ContextParser" because you end up with "ContextParserParser.java" and "ContextParserLexer.java" when you generate the parser--rather confusing. I also took liberty to remove labeling an variables (I don't used them because I work with XPath expressions on the tree). And, I reordered and reformatted the grammar to be single line, sort alphabetically in order to find rules quicker in a text editor rather than require an IDE to navigate around.

A grammar that does all this is:

```
grammar Content;
arithmetic: NUMBER | LPARAN arithmetic RPARAN | arithmetic POW arithmetic | arithmetic (MUL | DIV) arithmetic | arithmetic (ADD | SUB) arithmetic ;
comment: LINE_COMMENT;
content : comment | arithmetic | text ;
file: line+ EOF;
line: content? EOL;
start: file;
text: TEXT+;
ADD: '+';
DIV: '/';
LINE_COMMENT: '#' STUFF | '//' STUFF;
LPARAN: '(';
MUL: '*';
NUMBER: '-'? [0-9]+;
POW: '^';
RPARAN: ')';
SUB: '-';
fragment STUFF : ~[\n\r]* ;
EOL: '\r'? '\n';
WS : [ \t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
TEXT: .; // Must be last lexer rule, and only one char in length.
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This makes so much sense. I noticed that you have used `fragment` when matching all characters except and I do not. Is that one of the main issues with the original grammar?

Comment: Additionally, how did you check the tokens? I'm currently setup using CSharp build target and not java. I'm wondering what tooling you're using?

Comment: `fragment` is used when you want to make a rule so you can reuse the symbol, but not by itself produce a token. For C#, use my [Antlr4BuildTasks](https://github.com/kaby76/Antlr4BuildTasks) extension. It will make life easier in building Antlr/C# programs. It's on Nuget. If you want a demo, try using my [Antlr4Templates](https://github.com/kaby76/Antlr4Templates) and try "dotnet new csharp-combine" in an empty directory. For printing tokens, see [this](https://github.com/kaby76/Domemtech.Trash/blob/main/src/trgen/templates/CSharp/Program.cs#L150-L161) template. I have a slew of Antlr tools.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the knowledge! I'm already using your extension and I've been through some of the templates. I was going to switch to your Arithmetic implementation as it's closer to what I had in Nearley.js. However, as I'm still learning I wanted to keep it simple and grow my knowledge step by step!